# Как удалить папку Steam?

Tags: steam

описываю ситуацию:
Я хотел установить Steam полностью на флешку, сначала загрузка шла хорошо, однако потом пошло бесконечное: **Обновление Steam**, я решил прекратить это. Однако кнопка **извлечь** не работала, Steam установка не могла закрыться. Я решил вручную отключить флешку. Всё успокоилось. Однако когда я вставил эту же флешку обратно в ноутбук он начал очень глючить и опять пришлось вручную извлекать флешку. Я решил через переходник на телефоне удалить папку Steam с флешки. Вскоре проводник на телефоне завис, но получилось очистить папку Steam от всех файлов, кроме 2-х файлов. Я пытался из удалять через проводники на телефоне и даже через Termux. Ничего не помогло.
Прошу **пожалуйста**, помогите удалить данную папку(Без форматирования)[image: Ошибка в проводнике(в системном всё намертво щависало и всё)]
P. S. **Root** я не могу установить так, как Huawei

Comment: Отформатируйте флешку

Comment: Нельзя, много важных данных

Comment: Скопируйте важные данные, а потом отформатируйте флешку

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вполне возможно что это уже удаленная директория, то есть, что-то типо фантомной папки, вроде есть, а вроде нет. Нельзя удалить то, что уже удалено, это ошибка флешки, которая думает что файл есть, хотя самого файла нет. Поэтому при попытке удалить эту директорию, происходит переход по ссылке которая указывает на ничто, это как перейти на видео в ютуб и получить ошибку 451, единственный выход, это скопировать все важные файлы с флешки, и отформатировать ее, либо вообще выбросить

Comment: Тогда вопрос, почему Windows 10 очень тупит после подключения флешки? Как мне пользоваттся ноутбуком чтобы при включённой флешке он не тупил?

Comment: @Harikso я к сожалению не знаю, я уже довольно долгое время пользуюсь другой системой, с виндой сталкиваюсь только в школе на информатике